# Running Python Scripts in C via Exec?

Tags: python, c, bash, exec

I want to run a python script in C in the following manner: (I already forked)

```
err = execlp("python", "my_script.py", "test", (char*) NULL);
```

In bash, I can successfully run

```
python my_script.py test
```

(test is an argument for the python script)

However, the program outputs

```
my_script.py: can't open file 'test': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

What am I doing wrong? :3

Comment: Error is your answer. give full path of `"my_script.py"`

Comment: Is the current directory the same in both cases?

Comment: Yes. It is trying to open 'test' but I never told it to. It should be passing test as an argument.

Comment: Can you verify that the current directory is the same I.e by setting it from within C?

Comment: Also, try hard coding the path to Python to verify that Python will run correctly when run in this manner.

Comment: I don't see why the current directory matters. I have also tried hard coding the path to python. It seems as though it is trying to interpret "test" as a file to pass to the script when it just passes it as text when run on the command line.

Answer (score 6):

Ah, I figured it out. 
It should be:

```
execlp("python", "python", "my_script.py", "test", (char*) NULL);
```

The first argument, by convention, is the filename of the executable. I thought that this was automatically passed but apparently it is not.

Comment: Just FYI, there is no need ever to cast NULL, at least in C. I assume the same is true for C++, but I'm not totally sure.

Comment: or one can use ```system("python my_script.py arg1, arg2")```.